# Скорость чтение шары сервера, находясь на данном сервере

Tags: windows, сервер, сеть, администрирование

Подскажите, есть ли разница в скорости доступа, если я обращаюсь к шаре сервера, находясь в терминале на этом самом сервере?

Трафик пойдет по сетке и это будет дольше прямого обращения к физическому месту или Windows умный и сам все поймет, а скорость обращения будет такой де, как при доступе без шары?

Answer (score 3):

Если допустим вы имеете адрес 10.0.0.2, а сервер 10.0.0.1 и вы зайдете в терминальном сеансе этого сервера на его же шару, то файлы будут передаваться строго в пределах его сетевого интерфейса, то есть при скачивании или загрузке файлов сетевой трафик не будет проходит через вашу клиентскую машину(10.0.0.2). Вообще в таком случае обращаться не через разшаренные ресурсы, а по локальному пути.